# contact form issues - mobile number not sending

Tags: php, html, forms

I have been having ongoing issues with this contact form. I am now trying to get the mobile number part to work. 
I have been able to get it to work with someone code from here but it loses the format that I would like to keep. Can anyone find a reason why this form is not sending the mobile number?

site: www.krjwoodcraft.com

send.php

```
<?php

$name = $_POST['name'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$sender = $_POST['email'];
$message= $_POST['message'];
$mobile = $_POST['mobile'];


  $your_site_name = "www.krjwoodcraft.com";
  $your_email = "rob.catharsis@gmail.com";   


// setting header:
    $header  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";
    $header .= "From: {$name} <{$sender}>\r\n";

    //   to       subject               message       header
    $result = mail($your_email, "Message from ".$your_site_name, nl2br($message), $header);
    echo "Your Message has been sent";
?>
```

contact.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#send").click(function(){
    var name   = $("#name").val();
    var email  = $("#email").val();
    var message  = $("#message").val();
    var mobile  = $("#mobile").val();
    var error = false;

     if(email.length == 0 || email.indexOf("@") == "-1" || email.indexOf(".") == "-1"){
       var error = true;
       $("#error_email").fadeIn(500);
     }else{
       $("#error_email").fadeOut(500);
     }
     if(message.length == 0){
        var error = true;
        $("#error_message").fadeIn(500);
     }else{
        $("#error_message").fadeOut(500);
     }
     if(name.length == 0){
        var error = true;
        $("#error_name").fadeIn(500);
     }else{
        $("#error_name").fadeOut(500);
     }

     if(error == false){
       $("#send").attr({"disabled" : "true", "value" : "Loading..." });

       $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url : "send.php",    
         data: "name=" + name + "&email=" + email + "&subject=" + "You Got Email" +    "&message=" + message + "&mobile=" + mobile,
         success: function(data){    
          if(data == 'success'){
            $("#btnsubmit").remove();
            $("#mail_success").fadeIn(500);
          }else{
            $("#mail_failed").html(data).fadeIn(500);
            $("#send").removeAttr("disabled").attr("value", "send");
          }     
         }  
       });  
    }
        return false;                      
  });    
});
```

html:

```
   <!-- Contact Form -->
         <div class="row">

            <div class="span12">
            <div class="trac_contactform">
                <form id="contact_form" class="row" name="form1" method="post" action="send.php">

            <div class="span6">
            <input type="text" class="full" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name" />
            <div id="error_name" class="error">Please check your name</div>
            </div>

            <div class="span6">
            <input type="text" class="full" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" />
            <div id="error_email" class="error">Please check your email</div>
            </div>

            <div class="span6">
            <input type="text" class="full" name="mobile" id="mobile"  placeholder="Phone Number"/>
            </div>

            <div class="span6">
            <input type="text" class="full" name="subject" id="subject"  placeholder="Subject"/>
            </div>

            <div class="span12">
            <textarea cols="10" rows="10" name="message" id="message" class="full"  placeholder="Message"></textarea>
            <div id="error_message" class="error">Please check your message</div>
            <div id="mail_success" class="success">Thank you. Your message has been sent.</div>
            <div id="mail_failed" class="error">Error, email not sent</div>
            <p id="btnsubmit">
            <input type="submit" id="send" value="Send Now" class="btn btn-large btn-primary btn-embossed" /></p>
            </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>            
        </div>
    </section>
    <!--END CONTACT PAGE-->
```

Comment: Where are you adding mobile number to the email?

Comment: But JS doesn't send email, PHP does

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As  Hanky 웃 Panky correctly pointed out you are not including the phone number to your email message. Try the following code. I stored the `$_POST['message']` in a new variable called `$sent_message` and modified your `$message` variable to include the `$subject`, `$sent_message` and the `$mobile` variables.

```
<?php

$name = $_POST['name'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$sender = $_POST['email'];
$sent_message = $_POST['message'];
$mobile = $_POST['mobile'];

$message = "Subject: " . $subject . "\r\n" . "Message: " . $sent_message . "\r\n" . "Phone number: " . $mobile;


  $your_site_name = "www.krjwoodcraft.com";
  $your_email = "rob.catharsis@gmail.com";   


// setting header:
    $header  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";
    $header .= "From: {$name} <{$sender}>\r\n";

    //   to       subject               message       header
    $result = mail($your_email, "Message from ".$your_site_name, nl2br($message), $header);
    echo "Your Message has been sent";
?>
```

Comment: Thanks! it makes sense now!! I was not sure what to do with HPs response. I felt like I was playing the guessing game.

Answer (score 0):

You did not include it in your mail body. you have passed mobile number in php file. You got the file but you don't use it in your mail body.
include mobile number :

```
 $result = mail($your_email, "Message from ".$your_site_name, nl2br($message."\r\n" . "Phone number: " . $mobile), $header);
```

Comment: Thanks for the fix. I received one above which has worked as well by using a different method. Already gave him the accepted solution.